# How to create form inputs to add records collection on wordpress plugin page

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Simply, I need to create a form just like [this one](http://cledu.wpchris.com/) (at the top of the page).

The above is done using Gravity Forms plugin, but I need to create that kind of form on my own plugin admin page. 
I already know how to create a form on plugin page, just this kind of form element got me stuck.

Where should I start, what resources should I consider?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I'd prefer not to use any external plugin for that because of dependencies it would force for my client - just pure js/css/html/php or frontend plugin (like jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this plugin for creating form

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: I'd prefer not to use any external plugin for that because of dependencies it would force for my client.